# How to check and uncheck the buttons in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am beginner in iOS and in my project i have inserted "3" buttons for user "check" and "uncheck" the buttons as like below image..

Here, my main requirement is when I click the "checked" button, then It should be "unchecked" and when I clicked "unchecked" button, then it should be "checked" as like below image..

[image]

And remaining two buttons must be "unchecked" and for this, I have written below code but that is too lengthy process. Can anybody explain simple and short process please

### my code:-

```
 @interface ViewController ()
    {
        int check1;
        int check2;
        int check3;
        
        UIButton * button1;
        UIButton * button2;
        UIButton * button3;
    }
             
    @end
             
    @implementation ViewController
             




 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        
        check1 = 0;
        check2 = 0;
        check3 = 0;
        
        button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button1 addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(aMethod1:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button1.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0);
        UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
        [button1 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:button1];
        
        button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button2 addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(aMethod2:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button2.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0);
        UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
        [button2 setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:button2];
        
        button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button3 addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(aMethod3:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button3.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0);
        UIImage *btnImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
        [button3 setImage:btnImage3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:button3];
        
    }
             



-(void)aMethod1 :(id)sender{
        
        if (check1 == 0) {
            
            UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
            
            [button1 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            check1 = 1;
        }
        else{
        
            UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
            [button1 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            check1 = 0;
        }
    }
             




-(void)aMethod2 :(id)sender{
        
        if (check2 == 0) {
            
            UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
        
            [button2 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            check2 = 1;
        }
        else{
            
            UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
            [button2 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            check2 = 0;
        }
    }
     


-(void)aMethod3 :(id)sender{
    
    if (check3 == 0) {
        
        UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
        
        [button3 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        check3 = 1;
    }
    else{
        
        UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
        [button3 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        check3 = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: learn how to use tag in application for UIButtons... I will post short answer after 1 hour.. sorry its break time for me now...

Comment: ok i will wait for your code

Comment: I will post answer in 10 mins...

Comment: posted answer... Check and let me know if you need anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rename the images to check_0.png (un-checked image) & check_1.png (checked image)

### ***Step 1 : Declare one global in interface***

```
@interface HomeViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *selctionArray;
}
```

### ***Step 2: In viewDidLoad initialize this array & add data***

```
[self initArrayData];

-(void) initArrayData {
    selctionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        [selctionArray addObject:@"0"];
    }
}
```

### ***Step 3 : Create 3 buttons programatically and set tag to them***

First create three buttons programatically calling `clikcedButton` as click listener. Say button are button1, button 2, button 3.

```
button1.tag = 123451;
button2.tag = 123452;
button3.tag = 123453;
```

### ***Step 4 : Let's say first button checked***

```
// by-default first button will be checked
[selctionArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"1"];
[self updateMyButtons];

-(void) updateMyButtons {
    UIButton *mButton;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        mButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:123451+i];
        [mButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"check_%@.png", [selctionArray objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

### ***Step 5 : Now let's implement IBAction***

```
-(IBAction)clikcedButton:(id)sender {
    [self initArrayData];
    UIButton *mButton = (UIButton *) sender;
    int clickedButtonTag = mButton.tag;
    clickedButtonTag = clickedButtonTag - 123451;
    [selctionArray replaceObjectAtIndex:clickedButtonTag withObject:@"1"];
    [self updateMyButtons];
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Please do like . its so simple

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(aMethod1:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0);

    UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
    UIImage *selected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];

    [button1 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setImage:selected forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    button1.selected = NO;




- (void)aMethod1:(UIButton *)btn{
    btn.selected = !btn.selected;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try below Code, its simple Solution.

```
BOOL checked;
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    checked = YES;  //Set depending on your initial state
}

-(IBACtion)pressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    checked = !checked;
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:((checked) ? @"check2.png" : @"NOTCHECKEDIMAGE.png")] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

**might be helpful to you.**

## another Solution

```
// when you setup your button,eg. in Your ViewDidLoad method set an image for the selected and normal states
[myCheckBoxButton setImage:nonCheckedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myCheckBoxButton setImage:nonCheckedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

- (void)myCheckboxToggle:(id)sender
{
    myCheckboxButton.selected = !myCheckboxButton.selected; // toggle the selected property, just a simple BOOL
}
```

Here is the Diff Library also available, You can also try them

> 1. [DLRadioButton](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton)
> 2. [RadioButton-ios](https://github.com/onegray/RadioButton-ios)
> 3. [TNRadioButtonGroup](https://github.com/frederik-jacques/TNRadioButtonGroup)
> 4. [SSRadioButtonsController](https://github.com/shamasshahid/SSRadioButtonsController)
> 5. [VCRadioButton](https://github.com/vcepeda858/VCRadioButton)
> 6. [TNRadioButtonGroup](https://github.com/frederik-jacques/TNRadioButtonGroup)

Comment: @NSPratik, i have read and give proper Solution. we can only give Nearest Solution, we cant write full code, he has to do that. i should give him HInt or Help him. if tou have answer then Please Post it. to edit answer is easy, but write the perfect solution is not as easy.

Comment: Actually the question man want to manage multiple buttons and their selected state, that's why I told you..

Comment: yea,, Pratik, i m also from Ahmedabad, for which company you have Worked ?

Comment: @Pratik, i agree with you. next time i take care of this thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92806/discussion-between-mehul-and-nspratik).

Comment: Here is my whatsApp no : 9979704648

Comment: Are you there, Mehul ?

Answer (score 1):

```
[_nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
[_emailTextField resignFirstResponder];
[_contactNumberTextField resignFirstResponder];
if (sender.tag==0)
{
    sender.tag = 1;
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
else
{
    sender.tag=0;
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this , will help you and make it easy

```
 @interface ViewController ()
        {
            int check1;
            int check2;
            int check3;

            UIButton * button1;
            UIButton * button2;
            UIButton * button3;
        }
                         


  @end
                 
    @implementation ViewController
                         




     - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            check1 = 0;
            check2 = 0;
            check3 = 0;

            button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [button1 addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(checkNdUncheckButtons:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            button1.tag = 100;
            button1.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0);
            UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
            [button1 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.view addSubview:button1];

            button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [button2 addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(checkNdUncheckButtons:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            button2.tag = 200;
            button2.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0);
            UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
            [button2 setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.view addSubview:button2];

            button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [button3 addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(checkNdUncheckButtons:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            button3.tag = 300;
            button3.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0);
            UIImage *btnImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
            [button3 setImage:btnImage3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.view addSubview:button3];

        }

    -(void)checkNdUncheckButtons :(id)sender{
            UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
      UIImage *checkimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
                UIImage *unCheckImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];

            if (selectedButton.tag == 100) {
if (button1.image == checkimage) {
[button1 setImage:unCheckImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
                [button1 setImage:checkimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
                [button2 setImage:unCheckImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button3 setImage:unCheckImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            }
            else if (selectedButton.tag == 200){

                [button1 setImage:unCheckImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
if (button2.image == checkimage) {
[button2 setImage:unCheckImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
                [button2 setImage:checkimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
                [button3 setImage:unCheckImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
    else {
     [button1 setImage:unCheckImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button2 setImage:unCheckImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
if (button3.image == checkimage) {
[button3 setImage:unCheckImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
                [button3 setImage:checkimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
        }
```

Try understanding and then implement in your code and then do it

Comment: hi raji when i uncheck the button it must uncheck

Comment: @Ramakrishna : Thanks for accepting answer... [I see you have many questions which answers are not accepted. Can you accept where possible to keep SO clean?](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5026700/ramakrishna)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below correction in your code.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    UIButton * button1;
    UIButton * button2;
    UIButton * button3;
}
         
@end
         
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
    UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];

    button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod1:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0);
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    button1.selected = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:button1];

    button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod2:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0);
    [button2 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    button2.selected = NO; 
    [self.view addSubview:button2];

    button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod3:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button3.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0);
    [button3 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button3 setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    button3.selected = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:button3];

}

-(void)aMethod1 :(id)sender {

     button1.selected = !button1.selected;
}

-(void)aMethod2 :(id)sender {

     button2.selected = !button2.selected;
}   

-(void)aMethod3 :(id)sender {

     button3.selected = !button3.selected;
}
```

Thanks :)